# Replacing some characters from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i have a simple javascript variable:

```
var a=["varun"];
```

i want to remove characters[]" from string, so that resultant string is

```
varun
```

i have used following code to achieve it

```
a = a.replace(/[]"/g, '');
```

but its not working for me. Can anyone suggest me better way to do it.

Comment: actually `var a = ["varun"];` is an array with one element. It contains the string `varun`. So when you wanna have that string just use `a[0]` to acces it

Comment: As @Fuzzyma pointed out, you have declared an array containing a string element. So based upon your example, your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
text='["varun"]';
text = text.replace('["', '');
text = text.replace('"]', '');
```

You could test with:

```
alert(text);
```

In the console you will see "varun" but its actually varun as you could see in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

According to your declaration, `a` is an array, so please iterate the array to get the elements in the array.  Also, the string in JavaScript will always be shown surrounded by symbol `''`, but they are not the part of the string.  If you really needs to replace `[]"` in a string, keep in mind the square buckets should be leaded by the escape:

```
var b = '["varun"]';
b.replace(/[ \\[ \\]  " ]/g, '');
```

I add some extra space for the visual, you can safely remove the space in between.